# How do I crop an image per clipping path?

Tags: magick.net

I have a TIFF with one clipping path stored in the 8BimProfile. Now I want to crop this image along the clipping path.

**What I tried**
My first approach was to use the MagickImage Clip() method, which seems to do nothing:

```
using (var image = new MagickImage(pathOfFileToClip))
{
    image.Clip();
    image.Write(targetPath);
}
```

The workaround I am currently using calls the ImageMagick convert.exe tool:

```
var wrappedFilePath = "\"" + pathOfFileToClip + "\"";
var arguments = wrappedFilePath + " -alpha transparent -clip -alpha opaque -strip " + wrappedFilePath;
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = @"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\convert.exe",
    Arguments = arguments
};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

This works nicely and crops the image the way I want it. But how can I get this to work without the EXE?

Just taking the command line arguments like this did not work either:

```
using (var image = new MagickImage(pathOfFileToClip))
{
    image.AlphaColor = new MagickColor(Color.Transparent);
    image.Clip();
    image.AlphaColor = new MagickColor(Color.Black);
    image.Strip();
    image.Write(targetPath);
}
```

Any suggestions or links to working solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

So, turns out I was using the wrong method when applying the Alpha option:

```
    using (var image = new MagickImage(pathOfFileToClip))
    {
        image.Alpha(AlphaOption.Transparent);
        image.Clip();
        image.Alpha(AlphaOption.Opaque);
        image.Strip();
        image.Write(targetPath);
    }
```

I hope this still helps anybody who is trying this approach.

Comment: Strip() is not required crop the image. Strip just removes all metadata.